# What's Included in the F.E.A.R. Perseus Mandate and Extraction Point Boxes?

Tags: fear

I just got a copy of the *F.E.A.R.* expansion packs *Perseus Mandate* and *Extraction Point* from someone on eBay. The listing said that they were new, factory-sealed copies. Before opening the seals (curious rectangular ones as opposed to the standard circular seals usually found on game boxes), I examined them both (top and bottom) closely and they did indeed look clean, that is, there were no indications of a previous seal having been removed and replaced.

The discs look clean and in good condition (though the CD sleeves are kind of puffy and odd). However, my concern is with the remaining contents of the box, in that there is none. Extraction Point came with a single card with the default controls listed, but neither came with any sort of manual or any other inserts. (My used copy of—non-director's cut—*F.E.A.R.* included a manual and a notice card about multiplayer usage.)

What is included in *Perseus Mandate* and *Extraction Point*? Is this what they are all like or is my copy missing something (e.g. manual)? I tried looking around for some information, but could not find any on what's supposed to be in the box (which leads me to wonder if it's because there is none).

I should point out that *Perseus Mandate* is on one DVD, but *Extraction Point* is on two CDs.

Comment: I don't have either of those games, but based on the descriptions given I'd guess that you bought pirated copies.

Comment: I don't know; the boxes look pristine, the discs look like real, silk-screened, pressed discs, not burned ones with printed labels, the keys work, and the card looks professionally printed on glossy paper. If it's a bootleg, it's a heck of a good one. I'm just trying to figure out if these games are *supposed* to include paper manuals. (I'm wondering if maybe they don't because apparently the expansion packs are by a third-party company, not Monolith—which is why their stories are ignored in F.E.A.R. 2—so maybe they are "cheap" follow-ups to the first one as filler until the sequel came out.)

Answer (score 1):

My copy of *Extraction Point* (DVD case) has a DVD and a 24 page manual (about 4 pages of useful content).  There's a PDF copy of the manual on the DVD.

My copy of *Perseus Mandate* (cardboard box) has a DVD in a paper sleeve, but no paper manual (again, there's a PDF manual on the DVD).  There is also a 10-day trial DVD of World in Conflict in the box, though that may have been put in there by the retailer.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. My copy of *Perseus Mandate* is DVD, but *Extraction Point* is on two CDs. I wonder if only the DVD copies have a paper manual.